# How to display image over another ImageView in a GridView

Tags: android, gridview, onclick, imageview, drawable

In android, how can i display an Image over an ImageView inside a GridView when I click a specific item, always using the second image (not two image with two drawable but with only on image drawable) programmatically.

Any help? Thank you

Comment: Any workarounds? Did you try to follow any custom GridView example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you want to be able to show an image on top of another image. You can accomplish this e.g with a FrameLayout. In your grid view adapter, inflate and return a framelayout containing both your images. Have one of the images default visibility="hidden" and change it accordingly when the item is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should help If I understood your requirement well

```
 Resources r = getResources();
Drawable[] layers = new Drawable[2];
layers[0] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.t);
layers[1] = r.getDrawable(R.drawable.tt);
LayerDrawable layerDrawable = new LayerDrawable(layers);
testimage.setImageDrawable(layerDrawable);
```